# .End(xlDown) Alternative in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have realized that .End(xldirection) doesn't seem to work if you are trying to obtain from a different sheet. For example if you execute the code

```
Set A = Sheets("3rd sheet").Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
```

while you are not at actually at 3rd sheet, you get an error message saying application defined or object defined error.

I am sure I am not the first one to deal with this problem. Anybody know how to handle this without having to switch back and forth sheets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the `.End()`, is the default sheet.

Your code should be:

```
Set A = Sheets("3rd sheet").Range(Sheets("3rd sheet").Cells(2, 2), Sheets("3rd sheet").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
```

Or (as suggested by Cor_Blimey's comment):

```
With Sheets("3rd sheet")
    Set A = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
End With
```

Or (I like this best):

```
Set Sh = Sheets("3rd sheet")
Set A = Sh.Range(Sh.Cells(2, 2), Sh.Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
```

Comment: or more easily readable the above but with `With...End With` :)

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly reference `Cells` within a particular `Worksheet`, otherwise it will look within the currently activesheet, creating the error.

```
Set A = Worksheets("3rd sheet").Range(Worksheets("3rd sheet").Cells(2, 2), _
    Worksheets("3rd sheet").Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
'or

With Worksheets("3rd sheet")
    Set A = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
End With
```

The second version is much easier to read and maintain, just don't forget the dot when you need to reference "3rd sheet".

Comment: +1. Another option is to declare a worksheet object and use it wherever you need it. e.g. `ws.Range` or `With ws`

Comment: @HeadofCatering Yes, I do this constantly. I set references to the book(s), sheet(s) and ranges that I need, then I'm good to go.