# CountIFs in Excel whit VBA Code is very slow

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I'm try to use the VBA code for first time, I did a lot of search before to write these draft code, but one piece It isn't work well. 
I used the Application.WorkSheetFunction.CountIfs but the code It is very slow, I need to read a Table with 140.000 row and 31 columns, the table with criteria for countif have 6000 rows and 13 columns.

The code of Sheet2.Cells(x, 17), Sheet2.Cells(x, 14) and Sheet2.Cells(x, 17) It is wrong, but I can't found the problem

Follow the piece of code that I use to countIfs

x = 2
    y = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

```
Dim Submit_Date As Range
Dim GU As Range
Dim Legal_Entity_Country As Range
Dim Media_Type As Range
Dim Doc_Status As Range
Dim Approval_Date As Range
Dim Month_Create As Range
Dim FY As Range
Dim Status As Range

Set Submit_Date = Range("Table1[[#All],[Submit_Date]]")
Set GU = Range("Table1[[#All],[GU]]")
Set Legal_Entity_Country = Range("Table1[[#All],[Legal_Entity_Country]]")
Set Media_Type = Range("Table1[[#All],[Media_Type]]")
Set Doc_Status = Range("Table1[[#All],[Doc_Status]]")
Set Approval_Date = Range("Table1[[#All],[Approval_Date]]")
Set Month_Create = Range("Table1[[#All],[Month_Create]]")
Set FY = Range("Table1[[#All],[FY]]")
Set Status = Range("Table1[[#All],[Status]]")

For x = 2 To y
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Sheet2.Cells(x, 10) = _
            .Sum(.CountIfs(Month_Create, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), _
                           FY, Sheet2.Cells(x, 5), _
                           GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), _
                           Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), _
                           Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), _
                           Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), _
                           Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 10)), _
                 .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), _
                           GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), _
                           Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), _
                           Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), _
                           Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), _
                           Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 10)), _
                 .CountIfs(Approval_Date, ">" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 2), _
                           Month_Create, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), _
                           FY, Sheet2.Cells(x, 5), _
                           GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), _
                           Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), _
                           Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), _
                           Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), _
                           Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 13)), _
                 .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), _
                           Approval_Date, ">=" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), _
                           GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), _
                           Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), _
                           Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), _
                           Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), _
                           Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 13)))
         Sheet2.Cells(x, 11) = .Sum(.CountIfs(Month_Create, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), FY, Sheet2.Cells(x, 5), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 11)), .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 11)))
         Sheet2.Cells(x, 12) = .Sum(.CountIfs(Month_Create, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), FY, Sheet2.Cells(x, 5), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 12)), .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 12)))
'         Sheet2.Cells(x, 13) = .Sum(.CountIfs(Month_Create, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), Approval_Date, "<=" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 2), FY, Sheet2.Cells(x, 5), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 13)), .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), Month_Approved, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 13)))
'         Sheet2.Cells(x, 14) = .Sum(.CountIfs(Month_Create, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), FY, Sheet2.Cells(x, 5), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 14)), .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), Month_Approved, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 14)))
         Sheet2.Cells(x, 15) = .Sum(Sheet2.Cells(x, 10), Sheet2.Cells(x, 11), Sheet2.Cells(x, 12), Sheet2.Cells(x, 13), Sheet2.Cells(x, 14))
         Sheet2.Cells(x, 16) = .CountIfs(Month_Create, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), FY, Sheet2.Cells(x, 5), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9))
'         Sheet2.Cells(x, 17) = .Sum(.CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), Month_Approved, Sheet2.Cells(x, 3), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 14)), .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 11)), .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 12)))
         Sheet2.Cells(x, 18) = .Sum(.CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 10)), .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), Approval_Date, ">=" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 13)))
         Sheet2.Cells(x, 19) = .Sum(Sheet2.Cells(x, 16), Sheet2.Cells(x, 17), Sheet2.Cells(x, 18)) = Sheet2.Cells(x, 15)
    End With
Next x
```

Regards
André

Comment: You should use `with` blocks to make it easier to read this...I have to scroll like 10 miles to the right to see the entire statement and it just makes it hard to read...

Comment: André, for a good example of how you could write this using `with` blocks, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17868147/138938

Comment: This will be slow I am afraid. Excel is not a database. The lookups are a worst-case O(N^2) operation as it has to run (maximally) through every lookup value for each value to be looked up (around 140000 * 6000 = a big number). All of the COUNTIFS you posted above could be done in formulae (=COUNTIFS etc) without VBA - it might be quicker. Or you could look into using a DAO Recordset and running SQL queries against it, but this is probably overly complicated. Good luck - a hard start to VBA.

Comment: Hi ever one.
yes this is a hard start Cor_Blimey, but It is all that I have for today... Sorry My English is very bad.
Head of Catering, please, could you provide a example for this case?
I read the post that you sent, but I can't to apply in my case.
Regards
André

Comment: I edited your code to make it easier to read.  I agree with @Cor_Blimey.  You will never get the performance you want as long as you are doing all of this in Excel.

Comment: Thanks @mwolfe02, I start to apply the with function equal you show and discover that exist a limit to break line, so I Break line only when a conditional countIfs start.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what the criteria are, I can tell you that you would see a huge increase in performance by changing them. Aside from the first or second criteria, they all are checking for equality across the same several criteria.

Add a value, in a new column that concatenates (with a delimiter) the cells to check. Then check them against the criteria similarly concatenated. An example is that they are all checking for each row's GU, Legal_Entity_Country, Media_Type, Doc_Status and Status being equal to certain values. So, join those and then check the join against the joined criteria.

So, if you want to use formulae, add a column such as "=CONCATENATE(A1,"|",B1,"|",C1,"|",D1)", where A1,B1 etc are the relevant values for the row. Then your criteria will be the relevant criteria similarly concatenated. Then, change your countifs to be e.g. =COUNTIFS(**_**,combinedColumn,combinedCritera).

Doing this will reduce the number of lookups significantly, and accordingly increase the speed.

To change it in the macro do something like (just an example extract from your code in the question)

Old:

```
.CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), _
                           GU, Sheet2.Cells(x, 6), _
                           Legal_Entity_Country, Sheet2.Cells(x, 7), _
                           Media_Type, Sheet2.Cells(x, 8), _
                           Doc_Status, Sheet2.Cells(x, 9), _
                           Status, Sheet2.Cells(1, 10)), _
```

New:

```
Dim combinedCriterion As String
combinedCriterion = Join(Array(Sheet2.Cells(x, 7),Sheet2.Cells(x, 8),Sheet2.Cells(x, 9),Sheet2.Cells(1, 10)),"|")
     .CountIfs(Submit_Date, "<" & Sheet2.Cells(x, 1), _
                               combinedColumn, combinedCriterion)
...etc
```

Comment: @Cor_Bilmey I can't to apply this, You declare only the criterion and I received a error for combinedColumn, We need to declare the CombinedColum the same way that you use for criterion. Another doubt, I need to include after for `WITH` or inside the `With`. Thansk a lot

Comment: @user1902796 it was only an example - you will need to actually put a formula or something to make the 'combined__' things. Without actually seeing the workbook, I cannot do more than just try and describe the method - being to essentially reduce the work the CountIfs have to do.